# data-backdrop affecting another modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In a page I have 2 bootstrap modals, first modal (let say it modalA) with `data-backdrop="true"` and second modal (let say it modalB) with `data-backdrop="static"`. first i launch `modalA`, then from `modalA` there is a button which call `modalB`. when `modalB` show up, then i close it, the `modalA` is now not scrollable.

i dont understand why, anybody have a clue?

modalA config:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="photo-app" data-backdrop="true">
```

modalB config:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Answer (score 2):

> ### [Overlapping modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> **Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible.** Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom  code.

Answer (score 0):

what @cvrebert said is correct. I found the solution for this issue:

```
$('#pleaseWaitDialog').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

hope this help other people that in this situation.